# mysql replace accented characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

i would like to generate strict alphanumeric character logins from users' first and lastname. Since many of them are foreigners, their names have special characters (é, è, ï, ...). I would like to remove the accents (e,e,i,...) in the logins.

Here is my query. Is there a character set that does not contain accents?

```
UPDATE contacts SET login=CONVERT(LOWER(CONCAT(firstname,'.',lastname)) USING utf8);
```

Comment: i tried that: UPDATE contacts SET login=CONVERT(LOWER(CONCAT(firstname,'.',lastname)) USING ascii); but it shows ?? instead. is "ascii" the right character identifier?

Comment: You can't force a character conversion from X to Y if Y doesn't support all the characters that X does or you will get the ?? problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as a French computer scientist (with an accent in his name), I would strongly advocate against such a conversion.

Why, well, because this strategy is just replacing a wrong assumption with another wrong assumption. Let me explain myself:

We could see the fact that only us-ascii are allowed in login id as an incorrect assumption that "all user names can be *written* in ascii".

Trying to remove accents from users name is just replacing the assumption by "all user names can be *converted* to ascii".

That is also incorrect: It will work for me (as a European - Latin 1 proof named person), but how will you compute the name of 三島 ? or the one of Сахаров ?

I know my answer is non technical, but you should do whatever is necessary to allow non ascii chars in logins. Or, you should allow your users to choose this login.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution to normalize accented tags:

```
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(  
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(  
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(  
acc_tag,
'ù','u'),'ú','u'),'û','u'),'ü','u'),'ý','y'),'ë','e'),'à','a'),'á','a'),'â','a'),'ã','a'), 
'ä','a'),'å','a'),'æ','a'),'ç','c'),'è','e'),'é','e'),'ê','e'),'ë','e'),'ì','i'),'í','i'), 
'î','i'),'ï','i'),'ð','o'),'ñ','n'),'ò','o'),'ó','o'),'ô','o'),'õ','o'),'ö','o'),'ø','o') AS normal_tag
```

Comment: What about other accented characters like the Hungarian ő, ű, Ő, Ű?

Comment: @Calmarius Have you happened to have found a native function to do this?